# Can't Update, Delete, install Plugin

Tags: plugins

I can't solve this problem. This started after I created a new sub domain. I can't update my plugins, install, delete.

During an update it says "successfully update". After I goes back to my `plugin.php` it needs to be update again. I can't delete the plugin even it says "successfully deleted". And also installing a new Plugin it says "successfully bla bla" but nothing happens when I go back (or refresh) my `plugin.php`.

I tried file permissions but no luck.

So I Update my plugin manually.

Comment: Did you check permissions on the plugins directory as well as every file and subdirectories, including files within those subdirectories?

Comment: Yes, I did. I make the file permission to 777 to all directories and sub. and files but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

It is either an issue with your file system or with your mysql database.

On some webhosting configurations, Wordpress automatic updates fail. In my experience, if it is not file permission, then it is an issue related to file ownership. Try the FTP method. Add the following lines in your wp-config.php

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'ftpext');
define('FTP_USER', 'YOUR FTP LOGIN');
define('FTP_PASS', 'YOUR FTP PASSWORD');
define('FTP_HOST', 'YOUR FTP HOST (without http:// or ftp://)');
define('FTP_SSL', false);
```

If still a no-go, see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Override_of_default_file_permissions for alternative methods.

Answer (score 0):

Also check that version of PHP in `.htaccess` is correct.

You should see a line like that:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php
```

*(In this case it's for PHP 5.5)*

Note that you must do this at root of your WordPress site, not at root of your site.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Please just read the content: It's PHP 5.5

Answer (score -1):

try the following code in your wp-config file before doing anything in plugin

```
 define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE Asha. When writing an answer please do not just write the solution but also explain what this does and why you think it helps. More info can be found here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer